# Work out percentage to auto-populate HTML Table

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
function GetPercent($Arg){
        $Count = count($Arg);
        return /* Confused here */;
    }
        $Test_Array = array(
          "ID" => 1,
          "User" => "Test",
          "Perm" => 1,
          "Test" => "String"

        );
```

I'm going to eventually populate a HTML Table column with the `count($Test_Array)`, but I need to have the percentages to put inside the table attrib:

```
<td align=left style="width:XX%">
```

BUt, how would I go about working out the percentage?

Comment: `return 100/$count;` asuming that your array is as mentioned in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use floor() to round down so you don't end up with a total percentage of over 100%, and simply pass your array into the function to get the average width.

```
<?php

function GetPercent($Arg){
    $Count = count($Arg);
    return floor( 100 / $Count );
}
$Test_Array = array(
  "ID" => 1,
  "User" => "Test",
  "Perm" => 1,
  "Test" => "String"
);

$average_widths = GetPercent($Test_Array); // in this case will return 25

// ...table tags here etc etc etc

// output results
foreach( $Test_Array as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<td align=left style="width:' . $average_widths . '%">';
    echo $key . ' -> ' . $value;
    echo '</td>';
}
?>
```